# Can not receive all the SIGCHLD

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

In the following code, what I am expecting is the console prints ten `SIGCHLD caught`. I've already queued up the SIGCHLD by setting `sa_flags` to `SA_SIGINFO` and using `sa_sigaction` instead of `sa_handler`. However, it seems some of the SIGCHLD are lost. Why?

I'm thinking `fork()` might be interrupted by `SIGCHLD` so I use `SA_RESTART` to restart the `fork()`. I run the same piece of code on different computers. On my MacBook, it says `[1]    24481 illegal hardware instruction`. On the other Linux computer, less than 10 `SIGCHLD caught` are printed.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define CHECK(syscall, msg) do {                    \
    if ((syscall) == -1) {                          \
      perror(msg);                                  \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

void catch(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
  if (signo == SIGCHLD) {
    printf("SIGCHLD caught\n");
  }
}

int main () {
  sigset_t new_set;
  sigemptyset(&new_set);
  sigaddset(&new_set, SIGCHLD);
  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_sigaction = catch;
  act.sa_mask = new_set;
  act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;
  CHECK(sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, NULL), "sigaction error");

  int pid, i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pid = fork();
    if (!pid) return;
  }
  while (1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SIGCHLD` is a standard signal, which means multiple occurrences of it get collapsed into one. Linux kernel maintains a bitset for standard signals, one bit per signal and supports queuing exactly one associated `siginfo_t`.

Fix:

```
void catch(int signo, siginfo_t*, void*) {
    int status;
    pid_t pid;
    if(signo == SIGCHLD) {
        while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
            printf("child %u terminated.\n", (unsigned)pid);
    }
}
```

Also note, that you do not need to explicitly block the signal you handle because it is automatically blocked for you, unless `SA_NODEFER` flag is used.

And, pedantically, only a limited number of async-signal safe functions (see [`man signal-safety`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) can be used in a signal handler, `printf` is not one of those.

Comment: In this [link](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref%2Fs%2Fsigaction.html), it says "SA_SIGINFO tells the OS to queue this signal. The default is not to queue a signal delivered to a process. If a signal isn't queued, setting the same signal multiple times on a process or thread before it runs results in only the last signal's being delivered. If you set SA_SIGINFO, the signals are queued and they're all delivered." Does it really get collapsed into one? I tried your code but it still raises `illegal hardware instruction`.

Comment: Since `printf` is guaranteed not to be called concurrently in my code. It should be fine right?

Comment: @K.Miao Unless `printf` was interrupted by a signal handler which calls `printf` again. That may cause a dead-lock since `printf` locks the mutex of the stream.

Comment: @K.Miao The documentation may be innacurate. Only real-time signals can be queued, not standard ones.

Comment: @K.Miao Double-checked [Linux source for you](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/signal.c#L1029):  _... support queuing exactly one non-rt signal, so that we can get more detailed information about the cause of the signal._